# How to replace MySQL Server with Apache Derby as a PHP application database?

Tags: java, php, database, derby

What's the code syntax, and what all do I need to install and configure, for connecting to a Derby DB and invoking Derby Stored Procedures (which are really Java code) from a PHP Application?

i.e. In the PHP code, I want to replace the familiar `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_query()` calls with something that will connect to a Derby database instead, and execute queries and stored procedures there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to connect to **JavaDB** (also called **Derby** or **Apache Derby**) from PHP?

If so, you'll need **[IBM DB2](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.ibm-db2.php)** support on your PHP server.

Comment: I'm looking for an all open-source solution. Since PHP is open-source, and Apache Derby is open-source, why is IBM DB2 a closed-source product required to make this work?!

Comment: The answer is not referring to IBM DB2 the database product; it is referring to the IBM DB2 extensions for PHP, which can be used to connect to IBM's DB2 as well as to Apache Derby. Here's the link again: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ibm-db2.php

Comment: This article outlines the steps needed to do this: http://www.zimbio.com/Linux/articles/6tD_YZ0b7gd/Connecting+PHP+5+3+Apache+Derby+JavaDB+IBM

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [PDO with ODBC](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php).

Comment: I always thought of ODBC as a Windows API. How well does this work on Linux?

Comment: I don't have tried it with Derby, but I'm sure that it is compatible with Linux: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity